# ERROR 1052 (23000) at line 1: Column 'id' in field list is ambiguous

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to get all blogs that are having their related sites been expired before a specific date
blog is a table with foreign key for site (siteId)
here my SQL code:

```
SELECT * FROM blog b 
JOIN site s ON s.id=b.siteId 
WHERE (s.expiryDate < '2021-03-01') 
AND (b.plagiarismStatus=9 OR b.plagiarismStatus=1) 
AND b.isDeleted=0 AND b.isClosed=1
```

I keep getting this error:

```
ERROR 1052 (23000) at line 1: Column 'id' in field list is ambiguous
```

any help will be too much appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely both the `blog` and `site` tables have an `id` column.  You should explicitly list out all columns you want to select:

```sql
SELECT
    b.id AS b_id,
    s.id AS s_id,
    b.siteId,
    s.expiryDate
    -- plus anything else you want to select
FROM blog b
INNER JOIN site s
    ON s.id = b.siteId
WHERE
    s.expiryDate < '2021-03-01' AND
    b.plagiarismStatus IN (1, 9) AND
    b.isDeleted = 0 AND
    b.isClosed = 1;
```

When you used `SELECT *` you were selecting an `id` column from each of the two tables.  MySQL is rolling over and telling you that it doesn't know how to make sense of this.